# Evaluation Exception In Jasper Reports

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports, evaluation

I am getting following exception for one of my Jasper Reports.

The part of my ***jrxml*** file is

```xml
<textField>
    <reportElement x="813" y="30" width="25" height="16"/>
    <textElement>
        <font size="12"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[Pcs]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<line>
    <reportElement x="232" y="2" width="1" height="20"/>
</line>
```

The full stack trace of Exception is as  follows

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression: 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:203)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:591)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:559)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:876)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.java:421)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:406)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:257)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:473)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillBandNoOverflow(JRVerticalFiller.java:434)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnHeader(JRVerticalFiller.java:479)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:261)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:836)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:746)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
at Utilities.ReportDriver.runReport(ReportDriver.java:85)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.MainReports.jbtnViewReportActionPerformed(MainReports.java:864)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.MainReports.access$700(MainReports.java:19)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.MainReports$8.actionPerformed(MainReports.java:504)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
DetaiListlCustReport__1336728676796_795705
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.java:86)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:239)
at DetaiListlCustReport__1336728676796_795705.evaluate(calculator_DetaiListlCustReport__1336728676796_795705:227)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:190)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lost the double quotes for ***textField*** element's expression or you should use `${}` construction for variable, field or parameter.

The correct expression for constant string *"Pcs"* is:

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Pcs"]]></textFieldExpression>
```

The correct expression for the variable *Pcs* is:

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Pcs}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

This is valid expression (without double quotes) for ***staticText*** element:

```
<text><![CDATA[Static text]]></text>
```

Comment: This worked For Me <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Pcs"]]></textFieldExpression> Thanks a lot